# Pre and post backup timestamp at database leve in RDS Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I've a bunch of postgresql databases in AWS RDS.

Is there a way to get a timestamp value that informs the last execution before initiating backup? Similarly I need to find the timestamp post restoration. The idea is to confirm whether there is a change to the backed-up database before backup and post restoration and ensure that no transactions has happened in the meantime.

Tried with pg_stat_statements extension but it is of much help on non rds postgresql instances.

Thanks